# Extract value from video using regular expressions

Tags: regex

I have this big ugly chunk on code below. My question is how do I extract the value @videoPlayer param using regular expressions?

Thanks!

----BIG UGLY Chunk of Code----

```
<object id="myExperience121212" class="BrightcoveExperience">
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
  <param name="width" value="640" />
  <param name="height" value="360" />
  <param name="playerID" value="fdafafdafda" />
  <param name="playerKey" value="fdfadfafdadfafafdadf" />
  <param name="isVid" value="true" />
  <param name="isUI" value="true" />
  <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />

  <param name="@videoPlayer" value="10574655567001" />
</object>
```

..sorry guys, here's the full code. There will be some javascript preceding this, so using XML is out of question. I need a regex, that will work.

Update 2: Alright guys, if I can get the text inside object tag, then I can convert it to XML and parse it out. But how do I the code inside the  tag?

Comment: If you have well formed XML, then use XPath, eg. `//myobject[id="myE..."]/param[name="@videoPlayer"]@value`

Comment: XML is not well formed, as a matter of fact there will be a bunch of crappy comments & javascript preceding that.

Comment: Just cut the object part and you have an XML

Comment: You can use an HTML parser if it's valid HTML (which is what this looks like). Any decent HTML parser should be able to handle this easily.

Comment: Solved this w/out regex: 1) Strip out the javascript that surrounds <object> bla bla </object> 2) Load <object> </object> into an xml document. From here on use XML parsing functions to extract the value of the @videoPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all? Why don't you use a tool suited for the purpose, like an XML parser or some tag soup parser like BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 1):

If you **know** that the name and value attrributes of the param tag will **always** be in that order (name first), then this regex should work (untested):

```
<param.+?name=['"]@videoPlayer['"].+?value=['"]([^'"]+)['"]
```

If you **know** that the quotes around the attributes will always be double-quotes, you can replace all instances of `['"]` with `"` as follows:

```
<param.+?name="@videoPlayer".+?value="([^"]+)"
```

The value portion of the tag will be stored in back-reference $1.

But there are a lot of assumptions here that should be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/<param name="@videoPlayer" value="([^\"\']+)"/
```

Comment: That's pretty much the same as my answer.